# Python classes and objects, How to display contents of a list

Tags: python, list

So below is my coding and whenever I click on the button "Show average mark" it gives me an error

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Downloads\homework5_201599618.py", line 67, in showAverage
    for s in self.studentList: AttributeError: 'student' object has no attribute 'studentList'
```

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



class student :
    name = ''
    number = 0
    homework = 0
    average = 0


    def __init__(self, master):


        self.master = master
        master.title("student markList")

        studentList = []

        self.label_1 = Label(master, text = "Add student name:")
        self.label_2 = Label(master, text = "Add student number:")
        self.label_3 = Label(master, text = "Add homework mark:")
        self.label_4 = Label(master, textvariable=self.average)

        self.label_1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky = (W,E))
        self.label_2.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky = (W,E))
        self.label_3.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky = (W,E))
        self.label_4.grid(columnspan=3, row=8, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

        self.name = StringVar()
        self.number = StringVar()
        self.homework = StringVar()
        self.average = StringVar()

        self.name_input = ttk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.name).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky = (W,E))
        self.number_input = ttk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.number).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky = (W,E))
        self.homework_input = ttk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.homework).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky = (W,E))

        self.button_1 = Button(master, text = "Add Student Information", command=self.addStudent)
        self.button_2 = Button(master, text = "List All Students", command=self.listAll)
        self.button_3 = Button(master, text = "Show Average Mark", command=self.showAverage)

        self.button_1.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky = (W,E))
        self.button_2.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky = (W,E))
        self.button_3.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky = (W,E))

        self.lb1 = Listbox(master)
        self.lb1.grid(columnspan=3,row=7, sticky = (W,E))



    def addStudent(self, *args):
        self.n = self.name.get()
        self.num = self.number.get()
        self.hw = self.homework.get()
        self.studentList.append([self.n, self.num, self.hw])

    def listAll(self):
        self.lb1.delete(0, END)
        for s in self.studentList:
            self.lb1.insert(END,s[0] + "   " + s[1] + " = " + s[2])

    def showAverage(self):

        self.total = 0
        for s in self.studentList:
            self.total += int(s[2])
        self.average.set(int(self.total/len(self.studentList)))


root = Tk()
gui_markList = student(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I think the problem is in the def(showAverage) piece of coding.
Could someone please help?

Comment: The problem is in `__init__`, where you're creating a local `studentList` not an instance attribute...

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__` method, you need to change `studentList = []` to `self.studentList = []`

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
self.studentList.append([self.n, self.num, self.hw])
```

studentList must be defined/assigned value before.

In your code, what you did is:

```
def __init__(self, master):


    self.master = master
    master.title("student markList")

    studentList = []
```

So studentList is not assigned to self/the object as a result self.studentList is not defined.

You can solve the modify it as:

```
def __init__(self, master):


    self.master = master
    master.title("student markList")

    self.studentList = []
```